# Where to put custom eloquent methods while implementing Repository Pattern

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I am implementing **Repository Pattern** in a large scale laravel app. I have put almost all sophisticated and reusable database logic in these model repositories and i feel its helpful and more organised. All the entity creations, retrieval  etc code live in these repositories now.

But my confusion is: what should I do with the custom eloquent methods, for example I have a model with methods such as `$model->canPerformXTask()`, `$model->isActive()`, `$model->hasTooltip()` etc.

There are instances where I just want to use these methods to perform some logic in controllers or services. What should I do with these if I am implementing **Repository Pattern** ?

- Should I create these methods inside ModelRepository?
- Is it okay to have db logic in repositories but also use the eloquent models outside of it ?
- Does having a repository pattern means "use eloquent models within the repositories only?"

Any insight on this will be very helpful...

Comment: Does your repository have a `find` method, returning the Model with a given id? You can use `$this->repository->find($id)->isActive()`, or `$this->repository->find($id)->hasTooltip()`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more an opinion answer for everyone, and the debate will never end on this topic.

But, there's an expert answer by ***Povilas Korop*** on his youtube channel ***"Laravel Dialy"*** where he talks about this topic. you can find it with

> "Laravel Code Review: Why NOT Use Repository Pattern?"